# Change button to dropdwon when in mobile view

Tags: javascript, css

I need help to change this `isotope` button to dropdown when​​ it's in mobile view. Currently it's horizontal in desktop view, but need to change it to dropdown while viewing in mobile.

```
<div class="button-filter js-filter isotope-filter">            
    <button data-filter="*" class="is-active">All</button>
    <button data-filter=".commercial">Commercial</button>
    <button data-filter=".conservation">Conservation</button>
    <button data-filter=".industrial">Industrial</button>
    <button data-filter=".institutional">Institutional</button>
    <button data-filter=".mixed">Mixed Development</button>
    <button data-filter=".industrial">Residential</button>
    <button data-filter=".substation">Substation</button>
    <button data-filter=".infrastructure">Infrastructure</button>
</div>  

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $grid = $('.list').isotope({
        // options
        itemSelector: '.list__item',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        masonry: {
          gutter: 0
        }
      });
      // filter items on button click
      $('.js-filter').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
        var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
        $( '.js-filter button' ).removeClass( 'is-active' );
        $( this ).addClass( 'is-active' );
      });       

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css media queries to display the button as a dropdown
For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
button-filter {
*Your css styling*
 }
}
```

Comment: how to convert <button> to dropdown sir?

Answer (score 0):

I found what i need at here. Filter change to select option. but its using 2 code for 2 different screen

```
<p class="holder-filter-buttons"><button data-filter="*">Все</button><!--
                        --><button data-filter=".pages-aids">Пособия</button><!--
                        --><button data-filter=".pages-articles">Статьи</button><!--
                        --><button data-filter=".pages-grammar">Грамматика</button><!--
                        --><button data-filter=".pages-reading">Чтение</button><!--
                        --><button data-filter=".pages-tests">Тесты</button><!--
                        --><button data-filter=".pages-transcripts">Транскрипты</button></p>
                    <p class="holder-filter-select"><select class="filter-select">
                            <option value="*" selected="selected">Все</option>
                            <option value=".pages-aids">Пособия</option>
                            <option value=".pages-articles">Статьи</option>
                            <option value=".pages-grammar">Грамматика</option>
                            <option value=".pages-reading">Чтение</option>
                            <option value=".pages-tests">Тесты</option>
                            <option value=".pages-transcripts">Транскрипты</option></select></p>
```